# How to show on Console the console.log(response)?

Tags: php, ajax, reference

I have recently had some problems to show on Console screen the following $.ajax script, present in javascript code:

```
function getRoot(){
    var root="http://"+document.location.hostname+"/login_AMUBA/";
    return root;
}

$("#formCadastro").on("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var dados=$(this).serialize();
    
    $.ajax({
        url: getRoot()+'controllers/controllerCadastro',
        type: 'post',
        dataType:'json',
        data: dados,
        success: function (response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

To validate all form data, I created a Class folder with the file named ClassValidate.php, that validate the script above

```
public function validateFinalCad($arrVar)
    {
        if (count($this->getErro()) > 0) {
            $arrResponse = [
                "retorno" => "erro",
                "erros" => $this->getErro()
            ];
        } else {
            /*$this->cadastro->insertCad($arrVar);*/
        }
        return json_encode($arrResponse);
    }
```

The final code which (should) show in Console's screen is present in another folder named controller and a file named controllerRegister:

```
echo $validate->validateFinalCad($arrVar);
```

Actually, even when I force an error, the error don't appear. However, if I fill all the form correctly it sends to Data Base. What could be the problem?